# ActiveSupport Notification - Printing to console or log to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I want to trigger a creation of a new object when an object of my FbPlace class (mongo document) is updated. FbPlace is only updated through a script in the console or rake task.
Is it possible to check if my subscription to my fb_places is getting triggered correctly in my `rails s` tab or in my log files?

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("fb_places_updated.graph_engine") do |*args|
  puts "WORKS"
  Rails.logger.debug("+++ WORKS")
  #Other irrelevant logic 
end
```

I've added `puts` and `Rails.logger.debug` to see if the Notification is getting triggered when I do something like `FbPlace.update_attribute(name: "test_name")`, but I haven't seen anything print to console or my log file yet.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specified where you actually subscribe to the event. I would image you do it in an initializer and the rake task loads the environment so it should be fine.

To see that the block gets evaluated when the event occurs, you can use [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/), that way you can just type `args` and see what's inside. Put it into you Gemfile and then:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("fb_places_updated.graph_engine") do |*args|
  binding.pry
end
```

Run the rake task. If you did not end up in a Pry session, the event was not triggered. I'm not sure what should trigger the `fb_places_updated.graph_engine` event. I take it you use `mongoid` and as far as I know it doesn't trigger any instrumentations - there needs to be the other side:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("fb_places_updated.graph_engine", some_data: 42)
```

If that's the case, I wouldn't bother with notifications and just use [after_update callback](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#callbacks) or an [observer](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#observers) in the model.